# React native - How to write unit test for native code as SharedPreferences,

Tags: android, unit-testing, react-native, react-redux, jestjs

I'm developing a mobile write by react native,I've used a `"react-native-shared-preferences": "0.0.8"` to save data to share preference to Android device, so when I write unit test (I used Jest library) and I found an issue. This is an exception will be appeared when code test run, while the code run well without unit test.

How can I have resolved it? and How can I write unit test by jest for native code ?